# How to enable taskbar labels in Continuum?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, continuum

I use my Windows computer with taskbar labels, as seen on the following picture:

[image]

Can this be done on Windows 10 Mobile with Continuum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst this option remains in the desktop edition of Windows 10, there is no taskbar customisation to enable this when running a phone in continuum mode. (As tested with a retail Lumia 950)